# Occupy the free space at bottom of previous div

Tags: html

Find the below html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.numbercontainer{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
.number{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.head{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#29ABE2;
}
li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="numbercontainer">
        <div class="number">
            <div class="head">One</div>
            <li>1</li>
        </div> 
        <div class="number">
            <div class="head">Two</div>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </div> 
        <div class="number">
            <div class="head">Three</div>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </div> 
        <div class="number">
            <div class="head">Four</div>
            <li>1</li>
        </div> 
        <div class="number">
            <div class="head">Five</div>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </div> 
        <div class="number">
            <div class="head">Six</div>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this sample i have displayed the div(class="number") element in column wise 2 columns per row. One, and two comes in first row and then three, four...
first div "One" has less contents, so its height is small, two has more content so its height is big. because of second div has more height, first row takes second div height.Now the third div comes in second row and i want it to be occupy the empty unused space from the first div in first row.

How can i write style for this?

Regards,
karthik.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you mean. Can you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Aaron: jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2jk6U/ i need first column in the second row need to occupy empty space in the first column of first row. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

left column float to left, and right column float to right:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jk6U/1/

```
.number{
    width:100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.number:nth-child(odd) {
    float:left;
}
.number:nth-child(even) {
    float:right;
}
```

if you need higher cross-browser compatibility, add class="even" and class="odd" to corresponding elements. and styling with:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jk6U/2/

```
.number{
    width:100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.number.odd {
    float:left;
}
.number.even {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: How can i do this if 4 columns per row?

Comment: in this case you have to use the tech called "waterfall", caculate the position of each div dynamically, like pinterest.com. of course, you can implement it with third-party plugin/libary. like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: please choose a plugin, and read its manual. or just google waterfall or pinterest, and you'll find a demo.

Comment: BTW, check this out: jsfiddle.net/2jk6U/4 using css columns, not perfect for you, and do not support old browsers. just want to let you know, it's also an option.